# Mapnik Shapefile datasource runtime error

Tags: runtime-error, datasource, shapefile, mapnik

I am new to manpnik, facing similar problem. mapnik throws runtime error message                     every time I try to compile a sample code from python geospatial dev book.
here's the root of the problem.

```
datasource = mapnik.Shapefile(file="world_borders.shp")
polygonLayer = mapnik.Layer("Polygons")
polygonLayer.datasource = datasource
polygonLayer.styles.append("polygonStyle")

error message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "createExampleMap.py", line 45, in <module>
    datasource = mapnik.Shapefile(file="world_borders.shp")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mapnik\__init__.py", line 341, in Shapefile
    return CreateDatasource(keywords)
RuntimeError: Could not create datasource for type: 'shape'


I'd appreciate help from anyone thanks
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error message, too. For me it was caused by my moving the `/site-packages/mapnik` dir out of the Mapnik tree.

Assuming you are on Windows, you might want to check your paths are sane:

1. start a command prompt in your demo/python folder and type PATH
   check that your lib folder is in the path
2. start python from the same dir and say

   ```
   from mapnik import paths
   paths.mapniklibpath
   ```

   this should output your lib folder, e.g. `'c:\\mapnik-v2.2.0\\lib'`

I placed Mapnik's `site-packages` in my Python's Lib dir, which screwed up `mapnik.paths`.

Comment: Had same problem on windows, checking and changing mapniklibpath resolved it for me.